# Representar projeto

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos

Estou buscando uma forma de representar um sistema em forma de balões, fluxos.

Pensei em usar diagramas UML, fiz uma parte, mas me deparei com uma dificuldade, de expandir coisas especificas.Sem ficar abrindo telas e mais telas.

Busco uma ferramenta que me permita expandir baloes, que vao do geral ate algo específico, mas que nao perca a visao geral(abrindo telas e telas).

Sugestoes?

Ja usei MindManager e Astah, mas me deparei com limitacoes.